# Convert MD5 to base62 for URL

Tags: php, md5, base62

I have a script to convert to base 62 (A-Za-z0-9) but how do I get a number out of MD5?

I have read in many places that because the number from an MD5 is bigger than php can handle as an integer it will be inaccurate... As I want a short URL anyway and was not planning on using the whole hash, maybe just 8 characters of it....

So my question is how to get part of the number of an MD5 hash?

Also is it a bad idea to use only part of the MD5 hash?

Comment: md5 hash is not a number, so what do you mean by "part of the number"?

Comment: md5 is a number represented in base36 encoding I thought...

Comment: You are half right, an md5 hash is a hex number represented in base 16 (a-f0-9).

Comment: No, md5() is by default converted to base 16 (hex) but you can get the raw output from it as well.

Comment: An md5 hash _is_ a 128bit number. The usual representation is in hex, but that's not necessary.

Comment: ok, so how can I convert the hex to a number? I know that the number is too big for php to handle so should I use substr and hexdec?

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't believe he is talking about the raw representation of the hash here.

Comment: @Mark: substr and hexdec won't work since you cannot compute the whole number while breaking it in several parts with substr.

Comment: Using Base64 will make thing much easier, because it encodes consecutive 3-byte blocks.

Comment: @n0rd: base64 is not fully compatible with URLs.

Comment: @eyze - but if I only want part of the hash anyway then whats the harm in just substr part of it and then hexdec it and then base62 convert it?

Comment: @Mark: I'm confused, you want to take part of the md5 (base 16) hash, convert it into base 10 and then convert it again to base 62?

Comment: yes... is it possible to convert straight from 16 to 62?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, but depending on the size of the number it may not be enough to store on a float variable type, I'll edit my answer shortly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a different thing here.. Since you are only interested in using a decimal chunk of the md5 hash why don't you use any other short numeric hash like [CRC32](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) or [Adler](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/mhash.constants.php)? Here is an example:

```
$hash = sprintf('%u', crc32('your string here'));
```

This will produce a 8 digit hash of your string.

**EDIT: I think I misunderstood you, [here are some functions that provide conversions to and from bases up to 62](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450).**

**EDIT (Again)**: To work with arbitrary length numbers you must use either the bc_math or the GMP extension, [here is a function that uses the bc_math extension and can also convert from base 2 up to base 62](http://www.technischedaten.de/pmwiki2/pmwiki.php?n=Php.BaseConvert). You should use it like this:

```
echo bc_base_convert(md5('your url here'), 16, 62); // public base 62 hash
```

and the inverse:

```
echo bc_base_convert('base 62 encoded value here', 62, 16); // private md5 hash
```

Hope it helps. =)

Comment: is it possible to work out what went into the hash? Just I am thinking if I only ever show part of a hash it must make it more difficult to workout how it was generated... right?

Comment: Right, but then it wouldn't be a hash in the true sense of the word, also collisions are much more probable to occur.

Answer (score 4):

If it's possible, I'd advise not using a hash for your URLs. Eventually you'll run into collisions... especially if you're truncating the hash. If you go ahead and implement an id-based system where each item has a unique ID, there will be far fewer headaches. The first item will be `1`, the second'll be `2`, etc---if you're using MySQL, just throw in an autoincrement column.

**To make a short id:**

```
//the basic example
$sid = base_convert($id, 10, 36);

//if you're going to be needing 64 bit numbers converted 
//on a 32 bit machine, use this instead
$sid = gmp_strval(gmp_init($id, 10), 36);
```

**To make a short id back into the base-10 id:**

```
//the basic example
$id = base_convert($id, 36, 10);

//if you're going to be needing 64 bit numbers
//on a 32 bit machine, use this instead
$id = gmp_strval(gmp_init($shortid, 36));
```

Hope this helps!

If you're truly wanting base 62 (which can't be done with `gmp` or `base_convert`), check this out:
http://snipplr.com/view/22246/base62-encode--decode/

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't make myself clear enough, the md5 is not functioning as an id... just as a way to stop a user guessing the next url... so the url is id=1&md5=dsf213sfe. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this: (Not all steps are in php, it's been a long time that I've used it.)

- Create a md5 hash of the script like this:

  $hash = md5(script, raw_output=true);
- Convert that number to base 62.

  See the questions about [base conversion of arbitrary sized numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352434/base-conversion-of-arbitrary-sized-numbers-php)
- Truncate the string to a length you like.

There's no risk in using only a few of the bits of a md5. All that changes is danger of collisions.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a Java implementation which you could probably extract. It's an open-source  CMS solution called Pulse.

Look here for the code of `toBase62()` and `fromBase62()`.

http://pulse.torweg.org/javadoc/src-html/org/torweg/pulse/util/StringUtils.java.html

The only dependency in `StringUtils` is the LifeCycle-class which provides a way to get a salted hash for a string which you might even omit all together or just copy the method over to your copy `StringUtils`. Voilá.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
$hash = md5("The data to be hashed", true);
$ints = unpack("L*num", $hash);

$hash_str = base62($ints['num1']) . base62($ints['num2']) . base62($ints['num3']) . base62($ints['num4'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3.2, GMP supports bases up to 62 (was previously only 36), so brianreavis's suggestion was very close. I think the simplest answer to your question is thus:

```
function base62hash($source, $chars = 22) {
  return substr(gmp_strval(gmp_init(md5($source), 16), 62), 0, $chars);
}
```

Converting from base-16 to base-62 obviously has space benefits. A normal 128-bit MD5 hash is 32 chars in hex, but in base-62 it's only 22. If you're storing the hashes in a database, you can convert them to raw binary and save even more space (16 bytes for an MD5).

Since the resulting hash is just a string representation, you can just use substr if you only want a bit of it (as the function does).

Answer (score 0):

You may try base62x to get a safe and compatible encoded representation.

[Here is for more information about base62x](//ufqi.com/dev/base62x/), or simply `-base62x` in `-NatureDNS`.

```
shell> ./base62x -n 16 -enc 16AF 
1Ql
shell> ./base62x -n 16 -dec 1Ql 
16AF

shell> ./base62x 
Usage: ./base62x [-v] [-n <2|8|10|16|32>] <-enc|dec> string 
Version: 0.60
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open-source Java library that converts MD5 strings to Base62 strings
https://github.com/inder123/base62

`Md5ToBase62.toBase62("9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6") ==>  cbIKGiMVkLFTeenAa5kgO4`

`Md5ToBase62.fromBase62("4KfZYA1udiGCjCEFC0l") ==>  0000bdd3bb56865852a632deadbc62fc`

The conversion is two-way, so you will get the original md5 back if you convert it back to md5:

`Md5ToBase62.fromBase62(Md5ToBase62.toBase62("9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6"))  ==> 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6`

`Md5ToBase62.toBase62(Md5ToBase62.fromBase62("cbIKGiMVkLFTeenAa5kgO4")) . ==> cbIKGiMVkLFTeenAa5kgO4`

```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a slightly modified Base 64 with `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`:

```
function base64_url_encode($str) {
    return strtr(base64_encode($str), array('+'=>'-', '/'=>'_'));
}
function base64_url_decode($str) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($str, array('-'=>'+', '_'=>'/')));
}
```

Additionally you could remove the trailing padding `=` characters.

And to get the raw MD5 value (binary string), set the second parameter (named `$raw_output` in the manual) to *true*:

```
$raw_md5 = md5($str, true);
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352434/base-conversion-of-arbitrary-sized-numbers-php/1743486#1743486